# Can I pull all php global variables into the function's local scope?

Tags: php, function, scope, global-variables

In order to use variables outside of a function, I have to do this:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

What if there are a lot of global variables, and I just want them all to be locally scoped inside the function?  How do I do this without maintaining a long list of global declarations at the beginning of each function?  I'm not concerned about best practices, or all the reasons it may be considered dangerous.

Comment: Global variables are a sign that you're doing it wrong anyway. But if you must... `$GLOBALS['a']`

Comment: yeah, I suppose that's a possibility.  I didn't want to have to go through and preface every variable like this though.

Comment: You *could* do `extract($GLOBALS);` but that is an extremely bad idea and might break anyway because `$GLOBALS` is itself a global variable and therefore recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ideally**, everything your function needs should be in a parameter.

```
function Sum($a, $b) {
  return $a + $b;
}
```

If you really can't avoid referring to variables outside your function scope, you have several options:

*Use the $GLOBALS array:*

```
function Sum() {
  return $GLOBALS['a'] + $GLOBALS['b'];
}
```

*Use the `global` keyword:*

```
function Sum()
  global $a, $b;
  return $a + $b;
}
```

*Use an ["anonymous" function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and inject the globals*

```
$Sum = function() use ($a, $b) {
  return $a + $b;
}

$result = $Sum();
```

Anonymous functions are more useful if you want to work with variables in-scope of the functional declaration that *aren't* global.

*[extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) them from `$GLOBALS`*

```
function Sum() {
  extract($GLOBALS);
  return $a + $b;
}
```

This last option will pull in *all* globals, and seems to be what you're looking for.

**But seriously**, parametize whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you doing something like:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $result = 0;
    foreach($args as $arg) {
        $result += $arg;
    }
    return $result;
} 

$b = Sum($a, $b);
echo $b;
```

which is then more generic, capable of accepting different arguments, or more than two arguments, and useful in a lot more situations.