# array and function php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm just a beginner in PHP coding. I've been reading through a tutorial, but having some trouble with basic PHP concepts. If you could help me, I'd be much obliged.

I'm having trouble understanding why the following code doesn't work.

```php
<?php
function sum($x, $y) {
    $z = $x + $y;
    return $z;
}

echo "$x + $y = " . sum(5,10);
?>
```

When I run it, it prints `Array + Array = 15`, but I was aiming for `5 + 10 = 15`.

Could someone please explain to me why is prints `Array` instead of the actual values?

Thanks! :)

---

Sorry about the typos and errors in the code.
Corrected it, but still trying to figure out why I cannot declare `$x` and `$y` within `sum(5,10)`.

Comment: You have to declare $x and $y first, and you should understand the scope of the variables -- $x, $y in your code can only be accessed within the function. It's not only php, but most languages does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I pull all php global variables into the function's local scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187786/can-i-pull-all-php-global-variables-into-the-functions-local-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, your code has lot of syntax errors. 
Here is the corrected code.

```
<?php
function sum($x, $y) {
    $z = $x + $y;
    return $z;
}
```

In the next line, you are trying to substitute the values of x, y. But where have you declared them?

```
echo " $x + $y = " . sum(5,10);


?>
```

First of all, you have to declare `$x, $y` and then use them like this.

```
$x = 1; $y=2;

echo " $x + $y = " . sum(5,10);
```

Comment: @LilisSkyremix pls approve the answer if you find it answered your question. ☺️

Answer (score 0):

`$x` and `$y` are only defined *within the scope of the function*.  The code outside of the function does not know what `$x` or `$y` are and therefore will not print them.

Simply declare them outside of the function as well, like so:

```
<?php
function sum($x, $y) {
    $z = $x + $y;
    return $z;
}

$x = 5;
$y = 10;
echo "$x + $y = " . sum($x,$y);
?>
```

Note that you do **not** have the give them the same name in both places!  For example, the following would return *exactly the same thing*:

```
<?php
function sum($x, $y) {
    $z = $x + $y;
    return $z;
}

$number1 = 5;
$number2 = 10;
echo "$number1 + $number2 = " . sum($number1,$number2);
?>
```

You'll want to read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  It is possible to create `global` variables for your solution, but reading the examples in the documentation will help more.  (Hint: search for the word `global`.)

Answer (score -1):

try this will work,

```
$x1='';
$y1='';

<?php
function sum($x, $y) {
$x1=$x;
$y1=$y
$z = $x + $y;
return $;
}
$x1 = 5;
$y1 = 10;
echo $x1 + $y1 = " . sum(5,10);
?>
```